# Force Parse to https using JS SDK -- app not deployed to Parse Cloud

Tags: parse-platform

I have a node + express app integrating the Parse Javascript SDK. I recently switched over to using forcing https and am now getting a bunch of these errors:

```
 The page at 'https://www.site.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://files.parsetfss.com/b4641fde-4f17-4743-bbe3-447c6c9c50c4/tfss-e125dcc3-ec9a-4d37-bb33-6438bbf78af8-file': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

I found this:

```
var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
```

However, since my app is not deployed on Parse's Cloud I can't use that. I searched `npm` for a `parseExpressHttpsRedirect` package but it's not on there.

- How do I force the Parse JS SDK to use https?

Answer (score 1):

The Parse file hosting domain `files.parsetfss.com` doesn't support HTTPS. However, you can modify the URL to `https://s3.amazonaws.com` to the front of the URL and that will work. Like so:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.parsetfss.com/...

Answer (score 0):

Also explained here if you need it : http://hackingtheimpossible.com/quick-tip-serve-parse-files-via-https/

Notice that this is not a good solution since Parse.com is likely to choose to change there image host one day. Especially since they are owned by Facebook now. My advice if you want to do it like this make sure you create a function which you use everywhere. This case if they do change something you would just change your function and not all your views.